# Por que essa função não funciona em Navegador Mobile?

Tags: jquery, json

Estou usando o código abaixo para pesquisar dados em um json, e funciona perfeitamente no Chrome e no Firefox, porém em navegador mobile a mesma não funciona, e simplesmente não retorna nada:

```
function searchTitles(e){
    var val = decodeURI(e);

    var data = Object.values(meu_json).filter(function(objecto) { 
        return objecto.titulo.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1 
    });
    if(data == ""){
        var data = Object.values(meu_json).filter(function(objecto) { 
            return objecto.categoria.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1 
        });
    }
    if(data != ""){
        alert(data);
    }else {
        alert('error');
    }   
}
```

Ao usar no chrome ou no firefox a mesma retorna os dados e `data != ""` porém a mesma em um navegador mobile, não funciona, simplesmente não acontece nada, nenhuma mensagem de erro.

Comment: Acredito que o problema está em `Object.values` por não ser compatível com a maioria dos navegadores. Tente alterar por `for..in` ou um `for` clássico. [Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)  para consulta da compatibilidade.

Comment: Consegue fazer um exemplo com for in para eu ver como é @LucasCosta

Comment: Respondi com um exemplo @LeoLetto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Talvez o problema seja o `Object.values`, você pode tentar substituindo por [for..in](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in):

```
var valores = [];
for (property in meu_json){
  valores.push(meu_json[property]);
}

var data = valores.filter(function(objecto) { 
    return objecto.titulo.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1 
});
```

Comment: Funcionou muito bem pra mim deste modo, existe alguma diferença de velocidade entre ele e o Object.values?

Comment: Você consegue criar um teste no [jsPerf](https://jsperf.com/) @Leoletto. Como não tenho o seu JSON, crie um lá =]

Comment: Entendi, obrigado pela dica, vou testar lá depois :)